# Select and count query not working as intended in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

The table contains (id, name, place, month, year).

Each month a random number of contestants will compete. The results are put into the table above. The desired report is to look as follows:

```
name, month, place, total for that month
```

Query tried:

```
SELECT name, month, place, COUNT( results.month ) AS Total
FROM  results
WHERE MONTH !=0
AND name = 'some name'
AND year=2014
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY MONTH 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

example output

```
some name, 5, 13, 1
```

Desired output

```
some name, 5, 13, 25 (or whatever the number of persons was for a particular month)
```

I understand why my group by month is not giving me the desired results. I am just struggling to understand what I need to do to get the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a single name plus the count of all contestants, then you can use a subquery.  It is unclear whether you want all contestants for the year:

```
SELECT month, name, place,
       (select COUNT(*) from results where month <> 0 and year = 2014) AS Total
FROM  results
WHERE MONTH <> 0 AND 
      name = 'some name'
      year = 2014
ORDER BY MONTH 
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Or for the month:

```
SELECT month, name, place,
       (select COUNT(*) from results r2 where r2.month = r.month and r2.year = r.year
       ) AS Total
FROM  results r
WHERE MONTH <> 0 AND 
      name = 'some name'
      year = 2014
ORDER BY MONTH 
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Comment: I was looking for the contestants for the month. Your second query was 100% what I was looking for when I asked my question. I only had to add 1 'and' after name and before year. I have a follow up question. I have multiple years, 9 exactly. Month 0 contains a unique list of users for the whole year. Could I go one more level and user the names from a month 0 query for each year and generate the list of names per season to use for the query you list above?

Comment: @user3672917 . . . I don't actually understand the revised question.  You might consider asking another question with sample data and desired results.